# The Name "___" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I seem to be having an issue with my project in Visual Studio 2012 where I received 21 errors saying the names(ddlstud,hidId,txtName,txtCoverImage,txtReldate,gvVidGame) do not exist in the current context. I have my default.aspx file set to read from my default.aspx.cs file.

Here is my default.aspx file

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="VideoGameWiki._Default" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvVidGame" runat="server"></asp:GridView><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblStud" runat="server" Text="Studio: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStud" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblReldate" runat="server" Text="Release date: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtReldate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblCoverImage" runat="server" Text="Cover Image: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCoverImage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblDescr" runat="server" Text="Description: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescr" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Add" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="btnNext_Click" />
    <input runat="server" id="hidId" type="hidden" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnPrev" runat="server" OnClick="btnPrev_Click" Text="Prev" />
    <asp:Button ID="Btn_delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
</asp:Content>
```

and here is my default.aspx.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace VideoGameWiki
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private VideoGamesWikiContainer entities = new VideoGamesWikiContainer();

        private int currentId = 0;
    }
}
```

<sup>[complete sources here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NrpfX3Rb)</sup>

(EDIT) Here is my designer.cs file as the methods that were suggested did not work unfortunately.

```
 namespace VideoGameWiki {


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    /// <summary>
    /// gvVidGame control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView gvVidGame;
```

<sup>[complete sources here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WsN3RnVX)</sup>

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check your designer file ([page].designer.cs) if all elements had been added correctly

Comment: Did you try Ctrl + Shift + F  + txtCoverImage (Entire solution)?

Comment: Please use the code markup here instead of posting a link to pastebin.

Comment: Please ensure that there is a Default.Designer.cs and that it has the same partial class reference as your Default.cs. `public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page`

Comment: Apologies Pierre, I was unaware that my code can be formatted on pastebin. I have checked my designer.cs file and all the elements have been added correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After almost an hour, it seemed to have been a random error which was solved by right clicking on the project name and selecting Rebuild and that solved the errors. :)

Comment: Hi, i used rebuid solution and rebuild website in the top of the visual studio page.. but it shows rebuild all failed.. may i know what to do?.. thanks